# File Synchronization for Cordova app

Tags: file-synchronization, server, synchronization, plug-in

we are building a cordova app and need to sync large files with our server. It is supposed to work like Dropbox. The files on the server should always be synchronized with the client files. I am looking for a software that can provide the following requirements:

- Server component
- Cordova plugin or API to develop a plugin
- Synchronization of the changes in a file not the whole file (files can be larger than 200MB and we don't want to sync the whole 200MB every time.

Do you have any recommendations? Thanks a lot.